# How to get header files in c++

Tags: c++, header, click, mouse

I am trying to run this piece of code in dev c++

```
void CheckMouseButtonStatus()
 {
   //Check the mouse left button is pressed or not
   if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
   {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("LButton pressed"));
   }
      //Check the mouse right button is pressed or not
   if ((GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
  {
       AfxMessageBox(_T("RButton pressed"));
  }

  }
```

But when I compile I get this error

> [Error] '_T' was not declared in this scope
>
> [Error] 'AfxMessageBox' was not declared in this scope

I am using `#include <windows.h>` as header.

I got the code from https://vcpptips.wordpress.com/tag/check-if-mouse-is-pressed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AfxMessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6se7cb.aspx) is part of MFC that ships with Visual Studio. You cannot use MFC with Dev-C++. You can use the Windows API call [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should do:

```
#include <afxwin.h>
```

Comment: Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.

pThread was nullptr. is the new error i get in vc++

Comment: That's an MFC header file. MFC ships with Visual Studio. It's not part of  Dev-C++. Developing MFC code with Dev-C++ is not a supported scenario.